# OCR for Devanagari (Hindi / Marathi / Sanskrit)

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, indic

Does anybody have any idea about any recent work being done on optical character recognition for Indian scripts using modern Machine Learning techniques ? I know of some research being done at ISI, calcutta, but nothing new has come up in the last 3-4 years to the best of my knowledge, and OCR for Devanagari is sadly lacking!

Comment: google scholar gives me a lot of hits for 'ocr hindi'.. maybe you could pick one of these papers and email the authors asking if they could point you to places/people still working on these problems

Comment: Paid OCR software is available, http://www.indsenz.com/int/index.php?content=download_area

Comment: questions about suggestions are off-topic here. It should be on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is surely too old to be useful, but is cool: [a video](http://vimeo.com/user1772169) of the Ingalls speaking on Sanskrit and OCR. ([Daniel H. H. Ingalls, Sr.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_H._H._Ingalls,_Sr.), Sanskrit professor and translator, and his son [Dan Ingalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Henry_Holmes_Ingalls,_Jr.), computer scientist involved with Smalltalk etc.) The first half is Ingalls Sr. describing a project to automatically analyze text, and the second is by Ingalls Jr. describing how he implemented OCR for Sanskrit from scratch.

Comment: An anonymous user proposed adding this link to the answer: https://tdil-dc.in/eocr/index.html (I think it was intended to be a separate answer of its own, not an edit to this answer, so I'm leaving it here)

Comment: BTW these days we get good results with the Google Cloud Vision API: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop

Answer (score 3):

FYI: There's an [article in the New York Times](http://nytimes.com/2003/05/15/technology/circuits/15jott.html) from 2003 referencing a tool called [ILT](http://www.cedar.buffalo.edu/ilt/tool.html).